# Error .Env - flutter web

Tags: flutter, aplicación-web

mi web que esta en producción funcionaba correctamente y hoy día apareció el siguiente error al ingresar al link de mi web, este error mencionado impide ver mi web, me pueden indicar que puedo hacer para solucionar por favor , gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Este error se debe al punto del fichero ".env", para solucionarlo debes cambiar la configuración de esta manera.

```
await dotenv.load(fileName: "assets/env");

assets:
   - assets/env
```